# I would like some help displaying js stuff on the html side of things

Tags: javascript, random

I am attempting to display my snake on this dynamic gameboard i made as well as randomly place food
on said board how would i go about turning my js into visual html.
now that i think about it i havent even made a tick function
I've stored the game board and would like to place food randomly within said gameboard
i would assume it would involve toggling a class tied to some styling in css but i do not know how to execute

```
const gameData = {
    getSize(){
        let sizeInput = document.querySelector('#sizeInput').value;
        sizeInput = parseInt(sizeInput)
        console.log(sizeInput)  
        this.validateBoard(sizeInput)
        return sizeInput
        
    },
    validateBoard(size){
        if(size === NaN || size < 10 || size > 50){
            console.log('not good')
            return false;
        }else if(size === '' || size >= 10 && size <= 50){
            console.log('good good')
            this.boardSize = size
            return true;
        } 
    },
    boardSize: 0,
    
    countDownTimer(timer){  
        if (timer >= 0) {
            message.textContent = 'Rendering ' + timer;
           timer--
        }
        return timer;
    },
    inputMessage(){
        let message = document.querySelector('#message')
        let validBoard = gameData.validateBoard(gameData.getSize())
        console.log(validBoard)
        if(validBoard) {
            let timer = 5
            let countDown = setInterval(function(){
                console.log(countDown)
                if(timer === 0){
                    clearInterval(countDown)
                    generateGameBoard();
                }
                timer = gameData.countDownTimer(timer)
                
            }, 1000)
        } else if(!validBoard){
            return message.textContent = 'Invalid entry. Try Again!'
        }
    },
    gameBoard: [],
    //currentSnake: [[x,y]],
    snakePos: {
        x: 4,
        y: 4
    }, 
    food:[],
    //directionFacing: [];
    randomfoodSquare(){
        let boardSize = this.boardSize
        let squareX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (boardSize + 1))
        let squareY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (boardSize + 1))
        this.food = [squareX, squareY]
    }
}

function generateFood(){

    randomFoodSquare();

}
let submitSize = document.querySelector('#submit')
function generateGameBoard(){
    let sizeInput = gameData.boardSize
    let startMenu = document.querySelector('#startMenu')
    let table = document.querySelector('#tb')
    startMenu.style.display = 'none'  
    table.style.display = 'flex'
    
    console.log(sizeInput)
    for (let i = 0; i < sizeInput; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        for(let j = 0; j < sizeInput; j++){
            let square = document.createElement('td')
            row.appendChild(square)
            let x = j
            let y = i
                gameData.gameBoard.push([x,y])
        }
        table.appendChild(row)
    }
    adjustBoardSize();
    console.log(gameData.gameBoard)
}
    function adjustBoardSize(){
        let sizeInput = gameData.boardSize;
        let table = document.querySelector('#tb')
        let row = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
        let square = document.querySelectorAll('td');
        let tableWidth = table.offsetWidth;
        let tableHeight = table.offsetHeight;
        let rowWidth = tableWidth;
        row.forEach( rowEl => {
            rowEl.style.height = tableHeight/sizeInput + 'px'
        })
        square.forEach( tdEl=> {
            tdEl.style.width = rowWidth/sizeInput + 'px'
        })
    }
    
    submitSize.addEventListener('click', function(){
        gameData.inputMessage();
        let sizeInput = document.querySelector('#sizeInput')
        sizeInput.value = '';

    })
```

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="startMenu" class="hidden">
        <h1>Beasteds Snake Game</h1>
        <h2 id="message">Choose your board size!</h2>
        <input id="sizeInput" type="text" placeholder="ex. 20 will give 20*20 grid">
        <input id='submit'type="button">

    </div>

    <table id="tb">

    </table>
    <script src="snakeGame.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 body{
    background-color: cadetblue;
 }
 #tb{
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    border: black solid 1px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
} 
#startMenu{
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 200px   ;
    background-color: cyan;
}
td {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: rgb(250, 251, 255) solid 1px;
    
}   
tr {
    
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
#snakeHead{
    color: darkblue;
}
````

Comment: could you please include also the html your code is expecting?

Comment: so sorry yes yes @DiegoD there we go

Comment: Make a div with color at snake position i think

Comment: first of all I suggest to create the conditions to see the grid using a set of css rules like: `#tb {border-collapse: collapse;} #tb td{border: solid 1px;width: 8px;height: 10px;}` that will show off the borders and will give a size to the cell. Then since you used the table, remove the setting of `display:flex` to the table. And after that when you want to highlight a given cell in the grid just set its `background` color via the `.style` property of the element or just apply a css class to the element that will set the background

Comment: I've attached my css as well the hiding and displaying of the board is handled in js